# Is it possible to convert String to ResultSet in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp

How can I convert List to Result Set. Is it possible to do this conversion?

Comment: while(rs.next()){
              list.add(rs.toString());
             out.println("rs2************"+rs.getString("Username")) ;  
          } I want to convert this list to ResultSet in main method.

Comment: not here edit your question and then update it.

Comment: Now you are trying to convert the ResultSet to List. In the title, you say String to ResultSet. In the description, you are telling to convert List to ResultSet. Also, duplicate.

Comment: _Convert List to Result Set_. Its not possible.

Answer (score -1):

I think you want an example....Just try this code

```
public class MyResultSet {

    public ResultSet getResultSet(List<String> headers, List<List<Object>> data) throws Exception {

        // validation
        if (headers == null || data == null) {
            throw new Exception("null parameters");
        }

        if (headers.size() != data.size()) {
            throw new Exception("parameters size are not equals");
        }

        // create a mock result set
        MockResultSet mockResultSet = new MockResultSet("myResultSet");

        // add header
        for (String string : headers) {         
            mockResultSet.addColumn(string);
        }

        // add data
        for (List<Object> list : data) {
            mockResultSet.addRow(list);
        }

        return mockResultSet;
    }
}


public class MyResultSetTest {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyResultSetTest.class);

    public MyResultSetTest() {
    }

    @Test
    public void testMyResultSet() throws Exception {
        MyResultSet myResultSet = new MyResultSet();
        List<String> headers = new ArrayList<String>();
        headers.add("id");
        headers.add("name");
        headers.add("salary");
        headers.add("age");

        List<List<Object>> data = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
            objects.add(new Integer(i));
            objects.add("name " + i);
            objects.add(new Double(i));
            objects.add(new Integer(20 + i));
            data.add(objects);
        }

        ResultSet rs = myResultSet.getResultSet(headers, data);
        while (rs.next()) {
            logger.debug(rs.getString("id"));
            logger.debug(rs.getString(2));
            logger.debug(rs.getDouble("salary"));
            logger.debug(rs.getInt(4));
            logger.debug("------------------------");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: So where does one obtain `MockResultSet`?